# Different results iterating over a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, foreach

My problem is simple. I have to print some key-value pairs from a hash. I tried two different methods:

**METHOD A**

```
#Fill hash from file ($fh has been defined previously)

while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    $counter{$line}++;
}

foreach (my($k, $v) = each %counter){
    my ($p1, $p2) = split(/$;/o, $k);

    chomp $p2;

    if($v > 0){
      printf "%s_down_%s %s %d\n", $prefix, $p1, $p2, $v;
      printf "%s_up_%s %s %d\n", $prefix, $p2, $p1, $v;
    }
}
```

**METHOD B**

```
#Fill hash from file ($fh has been defined previously)

while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    $counter{$line}++;
}

foreach $k (keys %counter) {
    my ($p1, $p2) = split(/$;/o, $k);
    my $v = $counter{$p1,$p2};

    chomp $p2;

    if($v > 0){
      printf "%s_down_%s %s %d\n", $prefix, $p1, $p2, $v;
      printf "%s_up_%s %s %d\n", $prefix, $p2, $p1, $v;
    }
}
```

Reading the code, I would say both methods get the same result, but, after executing it, **method B**, got the right results and **method A** printed just two elements (4 lines).

After running the **method A** several times, I can see that the elements printed change each execution.

Anybody knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `foreach` with `each` is wrong

```
perl -wE'%h=(a=>1,b=>2,c=>3); for (($k, $v) = each %h) { say "$k => $v" }'
```

prints

```
c => 3
c => 3
```

With `while` instead of `foreach` we get the correct behaviour.

That this is wrong can be seen from [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) (my emphasis)

> When called on a hash in list context, returns a 2-element list consisting of the key and value for the **next element** of a hash.

So `each` iterates and since `foreach` first generates the whole list (to iterate over) `each` is made to iterate internally in a (clearly) ill-defined way; this may exhibit an undefined behavior. We end up with an incorrect list of key-value pair(s) for `foreach` to iterate over (formed internally using `each`).

Read `each` page carefully for further subtleties in use of `keys`, `values`, and `each`.

---

A more telling example

```
perl -wE'@h{("a".."f")} = (1..6); for (($k, $v) = each %h) { say "$k => $v" }'
```

prints on my system

```
e => 5
e => 5
```

When run correctly with `while` the `e => 5` pair is returned *first*.  So we get that pair, twice.

(*Still trying to figure out why twice ...*)

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres  Updated the answer, both by editing the first example and the explanation, and adding a better example.  The upshot is of course the same: `for` is wrong and one needs to use `while`.  But, as for explaining the behavior when `for` is used, there is a whole lot more.  Thank you for attribution.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres  Glad it helped and thank you for saying that. It is a pleasure to interact with you :)